# Spring @Transactional one transaction of method at a time

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, transactional

**Required Solution:**

Every year accounts registers to DataBase and gets unique number from 1 to n. After year finish next year will be repeater from 1 to n when accounts register.

I have table which stores (example):

```
id     , available_number, current_year
someId0, 8000            , 2000
someId1, 2500            , 2001
```

Method snippet:

```
@Transactional
public AccountNumber getAndIncreaseCorrectAccountNumber(String current_year) {
    AccountNumber accountNumber;
    Optional<AccountNumber> foundAccountNumber = Optional.ofNullable(AccountNumberRepository.findByYear(current_year));
    if(!foundAccountNumber .isPresent()) {
        accountNumber = new AccountNumber();
        accountNumber .setAvailableNumber(1L);
        accountNumber .setCurrentYear(current_year);
    } else {
        accountNumber = foundAccountNumber.get();
        accountNumber.setAvailableNumber(accountNumber.getAvailableNumber() + 1);
    }
    return accountRepository.save(accountNumber);
}
```

**Problem:**

As multiple accounts register for the last day (last minute), accounts get same `available_number`. Noticed 4 accounts registering with same `available_number` in 1 second (with ~0.1 second difference between registrations)

I think it is related to the thing that one transaction has started then another breaks in and while one is not finished with `getting` and `saving` another `gets` the same `available_number`

**Thinking how to solve:**

1. Have read about `Isolation` and `SERIALIZABLE(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);` does prevent interactions of transactions with eatch other but It does not prevent from two transactions getting the same `available_number`. 
   Also read about `Propagation` and `REQUIRES_NEW(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW)` what id does is if new transaction appears while the previous one is not finished then previous freezes, then new is finished and after that first unfreezes and finishes. What is not clear is that in my case first transaction might get value, then it freezes, then after new transaction is done with the same `available_number`, first transaction unfeezes and finishes with the same `available_number` (or am I misunderstanding here?)
2. Another option is somehow transform this method in one SQL call. To write though `nativeQuery` update select which has the logic and does the storing and returning object (any suggestions?). This way only `@Transactional` should be enough?
3. Is there a way to store method `Transactions` in a stack and do one at a time (after which first transaction is closed and the new one is opened)?

Sub-question: is there a way to simulate multiple request `@test` and check whenever the new solution potentially works? (new account registrations will happen only next year)

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking

Comment: @JBNizet how my question is worth your answer and how does it lead to problem solving or have you forgot to add more comment? I have read documentations before and maybe I am misunderstanding some crucial point but another documentation to the previous ones is not helping here anyhow.

Comment: I'm pointing you to a very specific section of the documentation. Click the link, and read that section, which is about locking. That's the appropriate solution to your problem, and you're not saying a word about locking in your question, which leads me to think that you haven't read that part of the documentation (hence the link to that section), or that you missed the fact that locking is the appropriate solution (hence the link to that section).

Comment: @JBNizet now I understand what you have in mind. My browsed has loaded url in the beginning of the documentation (thought you suggest to read whole documentation from the beginning - my mistake). Will ready it, thanks!

Comment: @JBNizet I have read your suggestion and came to my previous code update: `Optional.ofNullable((AccountNumber) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(AccountNumber.class, current_year, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT));` and remove `save()` method because `@Transaction` is pushing modifications anyway. The problem I think is still not solved because if another transaction will occur, second one will get exception. I could try to catch that exception and somehow repeat the action again, but I think it is a bad practice. Have you had similar situation?

Comment: If you use an optimistic lock, retrying is the appropriate measure here. 99.9% of the time, getting an account number shouldn't need a retry since the probability of two concurrent client asking for a number at the exact same time is very low (at least if the method runs in its own transaction). In the rare case where there is a conflict, one of them wins, and the other retries. If you use pessimistic locks you should not have to retry unless there is a very high contention and the timeout for acquiring the lock is very low.

Comment: @JBNizet that is the case: `AccountNumber` is like counter of available number for each year. Several clients are requesting for let us say `2018` years number available/ unique for them. In real case there were hundreds of clients trying to get `2018` years available number in last minute and ended getting the same number (which created duplicated numbers which is a bug). With `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` in case several accounts get the same number, one does the modification and gets permission to be saved, I thought that others are thrown with exception but no retry for getting a new number

Comment: @JBNizet I think I get it now. I will use `optimisticLock` and will try my logic in `try...catch`. If in catch the `optimisticLock` exception will be thrown then I will repeat inquiring my method to get unique transaction (was it the thing you tried to explain?)
Also in tests I will try to put `runables` and will call my method several times to test if number duplicates does not occur. Do you think is the right testing way?

Comment: Yes. You need to call a method that starts its own transaction and gets an ID. If it fails, you call it again. And yes, testing concurrent calls is a good idea.

Comment: @JBNizet, btw, do you have some link or advise of how to test my method using `optimisticLock`?
In my tests my method is either creating new objects without throwing optimistic exception or if I use Runnables, I get new objects created with new id's

In interned I read somewhere that it is not possible to test it with JUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JBNizet wrote and I read in other articles, OptimisticLock solves the problem because it allows only one transaction which modifies the row to be successful.
Other transactions are thrown with `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`.
Then I used `try{}catch{}` to make a recursion on `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` to redirect back to the same method

Tricky think was that the logic of `getAndIncreaseCorrectAccountNumber` was in deep layer where in the same transaction a lot of other `CRUD` logic happened so I needed to pull my `try{}catch{}` just above the whole `@Transaction` top layer (else the main object was modified and not rolledback, so `try{}catch{}` seems to be working when it is above most upper `@Transaction`)

In code what I did:

1. In `AccountNumber` added PostgreSQL version of row for OptimisticLock

> @Column(name = "version_num") @Version private int version;

2. In repository layer `AccountNumberRepository` added `@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)` just above the method
3. Added `try{}catch{}` for catching OptimisticLock and enabling recurse to the same method

> ```
> public String submitSomeObjectWithRecursionHandling(@NotNull SomeObject someObject, @NotBlank String accountId){
>         try {
>         return submitSomeObject(someObject, accountId);
>         } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException | OptimisticLockException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             return submitSomeObjectWithRecursionHandling(someObject, accountId);
>         }
>     }
> ```

`submitSomeObject(someObject, accountId)` started `@Transaction`

What I have not managed to achieve was to write integration test.
So I created 10 of prepared for submission `SomeObects` and from Front-End send there request at once to be submitted and it reproduced the bug at first with dublicated `accountNumber` and later after my fix it showed the recursion is handling the issue

In case you have some ways to test this solution in integration test, let me know.